# CDI inject into existing object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi, java-ee-7

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class MyRequestPayload implements RequestPayload {

    protected MyRequestPayload() {}

    @Override
    public ResponsePayload process() {
        String result = someService.doSomething(foo, bar);
        return new MyResponsePayload(result);
    }

    public final String foo;

    public final Integer bar;

    @Inject
    private SomeService someService;
}
```

Is there some CDI service I can invoke that will process all the `@Inject` annotations on an instance of this class, injecting all the matching services currently available? This is needed for the case where objects are not singletons and are not created by CDI. In the above hypothetical example, the object is created by deserialization.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think its possible with standard CDI. But if you use the DeltaSpike extension, you can use [BeanProvider](https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/core/api/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/provider/BeanProvider.java).injectFields ... does what you want. Note that of course your Pojo is not managed (scoped) by CDI, only the field injections are resolved ...

Comment: @Jan: DeltaSpike uses standard CDI-API calls in that helper.

Comment: OK, cool ... so you can do it without Deltaspike ... although: why shouldn't you just use the convenient way ...

Comment: I would certainly lean towards the convenient way.