# How to do CDI/SE from Spock Test?

Tags: java, groovy, junit, cdi, spock

I have been using CDIUnit and other various forms of CDI/SE solutions to implement tests (junit) that do less mocking and use more of my app stack (integration tests I suppose).

At any rate, I also really like Spock for testing and thought it should be snap to mash-up something from CDI/SE space and spock to be able to make Specifications that have access to most of CDI stuff.

Many of the unit runners for CDI (CDIUnit, weldjunit, deltaspike, random blog snippets that do cdi or weld for SE) -- are that JUnit Runners, and don't really seem to mesh well for Spock.    After much tinkering I have distilled into a really simple thing:  weld/se + spock with really simple @Inject.  But it doesn't work.

It seems like  weld does 'start' and my injectable's post constructor fires.   However the reference to the injectable is null in the Spock feature method.   In a further test I did an @Inject setter rather than instance variable and the setter did seem to fire with a non-null reference, but by the time my feature method fires; the reference is null again.   I also messed around with making the Weld and container @Shared and trying to initialize in the setupSpec() lifecycle method; same results.

**Is it possible to do simple CDI things from a Spock test?**

Here is a sample hunk of Spock that display what I am trying to achieve:

```
package fhw

import spock.lang.Specification
import javax.inject.Inject
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer
import spock.lang.Shared

public class Chompers
    extends Specification
{
    def Weld weld
    def WeldContainer container

    def setup()
    {
        println this
        weld = new Weld()
        container = weld.initialize()
        container.instance().select(this.class).get()
        //container.instance().select(this.class)
    }

    @Inject
    def SomethingToTest somethingToTest;

    //@Inject
    //def setSomethingToTest(SomethingToTest sst)
    //{
    //    somethingToTest = sst
    //    println "setter fired  and somethingToTest is null?  " + (null == somethingToTest)
    //}

    def "my first Test"()
    {
        given:
            println "given I used weld wrapper spec From spock (instance " + this + ")"


        when:
            println "when I do something, in this case, like just haveing @Inject annotation"

        then:
            somethingToTest
    }
}
```

### **UPDATE**

I have something kinda "working".  Not sure why or how and not sure if it even is any good (for a solution).   I would like to know more about what is going on and why.   Samples:

```
package fhw

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import spock.lang.*
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance

class WeldSpec
    extends Specification
{

    def Weld weld
    def WeldContainer container
    def me

    def setup()
    {
        weld = new Weld()
        container = weld.initialize()
        me = container.instance().select(this.class).get()
    }

    def cleanup()
    {
        if(weld)
        {
            weld.shutdown()
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package fhw

import spock.lang.*
import javax.inject.Inject
import fhw.spock.*

public class Bonnie
    extends WeldSpec
{
    @Inject 
    def SomethingToTest somethingToTest;

    def "my silly first cdi-spock test"()
    {        
        when:
            def s = me.somethingToTest.upShift("fred")

        then:
            "FRED" == s 
    }
}
```

---

```
package fhw;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named
public class SomethingToTest
{
    public SomethingToTest() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        System.out.println("SomethingToTest:  post construction");
    }


    public String upShift(String in)
    {
        String s = null;
        if(null != in)
        {
            s = in.toUpperCase();
        }
        return(s);
    }

}
```

---

### **UPDATE 2**

So I observed/surmised that really what was happening was that spock created an instance of my spec ('this'), and then in the setup using weld/se I created another with the select().get() calls ('me').  Simple printlns showed 'me' != 'this' and really the injects happened on the managed instance created via select().get().  Or so I think.

So what I think I really want is for injection to happen on 'this'.  Some googling and I stumbled upon this:  [CDI inject into existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750967/cdi-inject-into-existing-object) which is something similar.   I became 'inspired' by DeltaSpike's injectFields and refactored WeldSpec like:

```
package fhw

import spock.lang.*
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionTarget
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer
import javax.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedType

class WeldSpec
    extends Specification
{
    def Weld weld
    def WeldContainer container

    def setup()
    {
        weld = new Weld()
        container = weld.initialize()
        BeanManager beanManager = container.getBeanManager()
        CreationalContext<? extends WeldSpec> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null)
        AnnotatedType<? extends WeldSpec> annotatedType = beanManager.createAnnotatedType((Class<? extends WeldSpec>) this.getClass())
        InjectionTarget<? extends WeldSpec> injectionTarget = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(annotatedType)
        injectionTarget.inject(this, creationalContext);            
    }

    def cleanup()
    {
        if(weld)
        {
            weld.shutdown()
        }
    }
}
```

---

This works, and my spec is a bit more natural:

```
package fhw

import spock.lang.*
import javax.inject.Inject
import fhw.spock.*

public class Bonnie
    extends WeldSpec
{
    @Inject 
    def SomethingToTest somethingToTest;

    def "my silly first cdi-spock test"()
    {        
        when:
            def s = somethingToTest.upShift("fred")

        then:
            "FRED" == s
    }
}
```

---

Now to figure out if this is good for anything....

Comment: look at this issue, it could help: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/228340?tstart=0

Comment: Interesting -- saw that post last night but didn't scrutinize because the case involved Arquillian.        The poster's  work-around is OK;  but not sure it will help me.  It does add another data point; I am not the only one seeing this.   I have explored (well currently exploring) using a spock extension and tap into lifecycle methods like  visitSpecAnnotation() to see if CDI/Weld/SE would work better there.     Maybe I should look at  visitFeatureAnnotation() too.

Comment: What version of weld are you using? The main issue is that injection into your spock cases won't work, but there are options if you're on at least 2.x.

Comment: At the moment  'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4', and           'org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se-core:2.2.10.Final' .   Love to know more about the options; i'd really like to get this to work....

Comment: Spock extensions (using AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension) pretty much gets me to the same spot  can start a container but spock wipes out injections prior to invoking feature method .

Comment: @fwelland If you have an answer, post it as one and mark it correct.

Comment: @JaredBurrows  well I don't think it is totally answered; I had hoped some peoples would jump in and provide some additional design points or other efficacy feedback.      Judging by the anemic response so far; perhaps that is wishful.    I'll mark it correct shortly.

Comment: @fwelland Ah ok, if you don't feel it is ready, then don't, I just have seen this come up in my feed a few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per update 2; I have something working.

Answer (score 0):

Update2 has a performance problem: as setup() runs before each feature method, initialization of Weld takes place for each feature methods - with scanning classpath and all.

I moved it to static - but there is no shutdown in this case (I couldn't find a place for it outside of shutdown hooks, but probably it is not even needed for tests):

```java
class CdiSpecification extends Specification {

    private static Weld weld
    private static WeldContainer container
    private static BeanManager beanManager

    static {
        weld = new Weld()
        container = weld.initialize()
        beanManager = container.getBeanManager()
    }

    def setup() {
        CreationalContext<? extends CdiSpecification> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null)
        AnnotatedType<? extends CdiSpecification> annotatedType = beanManager.createAnnotatedType((Class<? extends CdiSpecification>) this.getClass())
        InjectionTarget<? extends CdiSpecification> injectionTarget = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(annotatedType)
        injectionTarget.inject(this, creationalContext);
    }

//    def cleanup() {
//        if (weld) {
//            weld.shutdown()
//        }
//    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feed back.   I didn't consider the performance  of making the cdi container prior to each feature method.     I did, however, feel it would be important to start with a fresh container per feature method -- and hence the penalty.   perhaps Spock's setupSpec() and cleanupSpec() would get rid of static block and give a hook at fixture shutdown?